# No Jordan normal form in $\mathbb Q^6$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $V = \mathbb Q^6 , \phi\in End(V)$.

$D_s(\phi)\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2&1&1&0&0 \\
-1 & -1 &0&1&0&0 \\
0 &0&2&5&0&0 \\
0&0&-1&-2&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{pmatrix}$

The characteristic polynomial is obviously $h_\phi(X)=(X^2+1)^3$, which has no zeroes in $\mathbb Q$.

How do i determine the Jordan normal form? Since $V = \mathbb Q^6$ and the zeroes of $h_\phi \notin \mathbb Q$ there are no eigenvalues to put into the Jordan Matrix or am i wrong?

Comment: If we considered the matrix entries as belonging to the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, you would be able to find the Jordan canonical form with a little work.  When the eigenvalues have rational real and imaginary parts, there is a form using $2\times 2$ diagonal blocks to represent them over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Is this the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: In order to achieve the JNF, it is *required* the base field contains all the roots of the characteristic polynomial, otherwise it can't be done...